# Where is the NCSO.jar and java in IBM Notes on a Mac?

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm using IBM Notes 9 Social Edition (Mac) however it does not contain this jar on the client.  Nor is it packaged with java.  Is the Notes API not supported on a Mac environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM Notes 9 Social Edition (Mac) does not ship with NCSO.jar, but you can retrieve it from other sources (as @Richard Schwartz metions).  It does work in the Mac environment but you need to be sure to use the JDK 1.6 that it gets hooked up to when IBM Notes is installed.  e.g.:

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk
```

Also, you need to ensure you use the -d32 flag to run it in 32-bit mode, as it defaults to 64-bit mode. You cannot use any new JDK version as the 32-bit mode is no longer supported.

Furthermore, you may need to update the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to point to your notes dydll library files in the Notes installation  eg.:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/IBM Notes.app/Contents/MacOS"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's not found on your machine - perhaps it's only installed with the Domino Designer client nowadays. But you can get NCSO.jar from your Domino server or from a Domino Designer installation on a Windows machine. There's no reason why it wouldn't work on a Mac.